# multilingual SMS solution

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, smslib

I am looking for  multilingual SMS solution , Which allows me to send via API , I tried some commercial solutions , but still no luck , the problem is in sending multilingual text , I have to send SMS in Korean , Japanese , Hebrew  , Thai , Chinese , Persian .

Is there any SMS solution which I can use it to send . SMS in above listed languages via API .

Just in case if you couldn't find any SMS solution , Please suggest a way to implement it using any open source platform which can allow me to send multilingual SMS .

Thanks in advance for responding to this post .

Answer (score 1):

[*Disclaimer: I do some developer evangelism for Nexmo.*]

I'm not sure of other APIs, but I know [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com) supports Unicode. From [the docs](http://www.nexmo.com/documentation/):

> Nexmo supports Unicode for multiple language support. Text length, however, is limited to 70 characters-exceeding 70 characters will have your message split into parts. Further, the mobile device must support the character encoding, for example, a US device may not display Arabic.

Comment: Thanks for the response , I am not worried about not displaying text in US phones or any region , Ignoring this problem , I am just looking for a solution which allows me to send SMS in these languages ( ignore whether it displays or not )

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara Then you should be able to use Unicode to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any pre-built open source tool to do what you are asking.  Howerver, you could build one without too much effort.  I would use the Google translate API to precompile a given message into whatever sought languages.  Then I would use an opensource SMS gateway tool like Kannel to transmit the messages.

Comment: Setting Up Kannel is too expensive and very difficult to manage it because HTTP access via API is too difficult to acihive.  any ways thanks for suggesting this  .